# Existence of partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I know how to compute partial derivatives of functions with more than one variable. But how can i assert that the partial derivatives of a given function exist at a point without computing it? Consider the following functions for example:

$f(x,y)=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ and $f(0,0)=0$

How do I show that the first partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ exists at $0$?

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: I know I can do it by computation, but the problem is not to compute it, but to show it that the partial derivative exists at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There are *two* first partials, but by (anti)symmetry you only need to show that one exists. So write it out as it is defined: show that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}
$$
exists. Note that before you can do this, you have to define what $$ f(0,0)$$ is--your definition as stated doesn't include that point.

**Addendum:** Since you added the definition that $f(0)=0$, the problem becomes easier. The limit in question is now
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}
=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)}{h}.$$
But note that for any nonzero $h$, we have $f(h,0)=(h)(0)(h^2-0^2)/(h^2+0^2)=0$, so this is just $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}0 =0.$$

In other words, we showed $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0.$$ By antisymmetry, we also then have that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$$ as well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to note that f(0,0)=0  It is indeed given in the problem @MPW

Comment: How can you conclude from the fact that limit is equal to $0$ the partial derivatives are $0$

Comment: By definition of partial derivative: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}$$ For the other partial, you can do it the same way or just notice that $$f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$$

Comment: @MPW  Can't we compute the partial derivatives and take the limit (x,y)-->(0,0)?

Comment: Only if you know that the partials exist and are continuous at $(0,0)$. It is NOT true in general that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$ (in fact, this is true if and only if $g$ is continuous at $a$).